# If the value of img src is changed by a JS click event why doesn't this value start empty when the page that holds it is revisited with back button?

Tags: javascript

When I used JS to first add and then delete an image from the browser I anticipated that the screen would render clear when I left the page and then returned using the back button.  However when I returned the image was once again present on the screen.  This happened despite the fact that the screen is set to start clear, i.e. `<img src="">` and before I left I used the `Delete Image` button to remove the image that I had added.  For some reason the image was there again.

**How to recreate this behavior:**

1. Open Page 1
2. Choose an image file from your system
3. JavaScript will set the value of `<img src="">` to your image and display it
4. Click the `Delete Image` button and the image will be removed
5. Click the `Link To Page Two` button
6. Use the back button on your browser and when you return the image will be on the screen again
7. If instead of the back button you return with `Link To Page One` the screen starts fresh without an image

**page-one.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    
<body>

    <h1>Page One</h1>
    <p><a href="page-two.html">link to Page Two</a></p>

    <p><img src="" id="theImage"></p>

    <p><input type="file" name="imageFile" accept=".gif,.jpg,.png" id="inputImageFile"></p>

    <button id="theButton">Delete Image</button>

    <script>

        let theImage = document.querySelector('#theImage');
        let inputImageFile = document.querySelector('#inputImageFile');
        let theButton = document.querySelector('#theButton');

        inputImageFile.addEventListener('input', imageUpload);
        theButton.addEventListener('click', deleteImage);

        function imageUpload(e) {

            let uploadedFile = e.target.files[0];

            let forViewing = new Image();
            forViewing.src = URL.createObjectURL(uploadedFile);

            theImage.src = forViewing.src;

        }

        function deleteImage() {

            theImage.src = '';

        }

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**page-two.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
    
<body>

    <h1>Page Two</h1>
    <p><a href="page-one.html">link to Page One</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is just your browser cache. if you use the same previous URL, it didn't send a server request, and reuse your last page in cache.

Comment: @MisterJojo I used the `Delete Image` button before I left the screen and the image was deleted.  If the cache is the problem why doesn't it remember I started with an empty screen, added an image, deleted the same image and then left the screen while it was empty?  If I left without an image shouldn't it return without an image?

Comment: restaurants do not say what they are doing in their kitchen. If it is not the cache of your browser then it can also come from a proxy (Web accelerator)

Comment: @MisterJojo It's on my desktop.  The picture was added with JS and then deleted with JS.  If the screen starts empty and I left with the screen empty why when I return is the image on the screen?  My simple example recreates it every time.

Comment: Knowing the underlying reason for this behavior of browsers is useless, you will not be able to change the behavior. which makes your message a purely theoretical question.

Comment: If you want to make sure that the page when it reloads is exactly as you left it, then you'll have to code that in JS, but that's a whole different question from this one.

Comment: @MisterJojo webdev-dan figured it out.  The `input.value` was storing the value.

Comment: eh? **webdev-dan**'s answer is just one of the possible solutions

Comment: @MisterJojo I tested his solution and it fixed the problem.

Comment: are you actually assuming I didn't already know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable explanation is that the browser remembers last successfully loaded content - when you change the source into empty string the browser has "nothing" to cache so there is a chance the engine of the specific browser (or all of them) leaves the cache unchanged - try changing the source into something like "pixel image" in your deleteImage function like this:

```
theImage.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGNiYAAAAAkAAxkR2eQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=';
```

it will load a transparent 1x1px png and probably replace the cached image.
...or use the cache controlling headers on the server - to tell the browser not to cache.

---

**on the second thought**

in your delete fuction add this line:

```
inputImageFile.value = '';
```

it works now ;)

it looks like the input plays the role - the value is being cached - and when browser sets the value from cache - i guess the 'input' event fires - and your script displays the image ;)

Comment: That was a good idea, I tried it and the result was identical.  I "deleted the image" and the 1 pixel image did successfully replace it.  However when I returned with the back button the large image was there again.  The simple example I included above recreates the issue successfully every time.

Comment: @myNewAccount it looks like the input plays the role - the value is being cached - and when browser sets the value from cache - i guess the 'input' event fires - and your script displays the image ;) look at the edit.

Comment: I tested it you were 100% correct.  How did you figure that out?  What could I have used to figure that out on my own?  I didn't even know where to start.  Also... what is wrong with my question that is causing it to get 2 thumbs down?  I'm scratching my head on that one too.

Comment: I have no idea about those thumbs down mate :) Might be that people looking for straight question like "What i have" and "What i want" below it. No idea. ...i figured the answer most likely from my experience... and since first solution failed - there has to be some other cache so i was looking for it.